# Button press and hold for action in Android PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, button

I'm need to preform a specific action in my app if the user presses and holds a button for a few second, if the user removes his finger from the button before the delay runs out, then this action will be cancelled.  I use 'ontouchstart' event for the press.

Is there any way i can achieve this using html and javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code snippets to achieve this particular requirement,

```
var pressTimer;
$("#btnClick").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  return false;
});
$("#btnClick").mousedown(function(){
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { ... your code here ...},time_delay)
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for keyup and keydown events in javascript

useful link:
http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_events/#keydown