# longpress event not working in Android using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using Javascript to handle the longpress event it will working fine when using on simple HTML pages, but when I'm using this code in Phonegap/Android, it does not work, the code is given below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var mousedowntime;
  $('#Button1').mousedown(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    mousedowntime = d.getTime();
    //alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
    //start a timer
  });
  $('#Button1').mouseup(function() {
    // debugger;
    //alert('Handler for .mouseup() called.');
    //stop the timer and decide on long click
    var d = new Date();
    //alert("mousedowntime=" + mousedowntime);
    presstime = d.getTime() - mousedowntime;
    //alert("presstime=" + presstime);
    if (presstime > 999/*You can decide the time*/) {
      //Do_Action_Long_Press_Event();
      alert("Long pressed.");
    } else {
      //Do_Action_Click_Event();
      alert("Click.");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `touchstart` and `touchend` events

So:

```
$('#Button1').on('touchstart',function() {
    //Logic
});

$('#Button1').on('touchend', function() {
    //Logic
});
```

Comment: No problem. If an answer has been useful to you, you should mark it as the accepted answer. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logic in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379126/1276002).  I hope this what you were searching for.